# Mysql : Get the count of all values in two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns X, Y. I want to count the number of appearance of each record in both the columns .
Eg:

```
X | Y

A | A
B | A
B | C
D | C
```

Result should be

```
variable | X_count | Y_count
A        | 1       | 2
B        | 2       | 0
C        | 0       | 2
D        | 1       | 0
```

How do I achieve this in mysql ?

EDIT: Okay, After spending some hours, I have ensured that all values in Y are subset of X. i.e. X_count will never be 0 for any variable. Does this help to optimize ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think you need a union temp table and group by

```
  select v.variable, a.count(*), b.count(*)
  from 
  (select x as variable
  from my_table
  union select y
  from my_table ) as v
  inner join my_table as a on a.X = v.variable
  inner join my_table as b on b.y = v.variable
  group by v.variable
```

The fact the Y are a subset of the X allows to avoid the union and then but anyway we need the distinct X

```
  select v.variable, a.count(*), b.count(*)
  from 
  (select distinct x as variable
  from my_table ) as v
  inner join my_table as a on a.X = v.variable
  inner join my_table as b on b.y = v.variable
  group by v.variable
```

Comment: I think you missed the typo of select after union. Also distinct are not required IMO. Is there any way to optimize the query, 2 inner joins are taking lots of time on the table.

Comment: I have checked for typo and updated the answer .. for optmize .. you can think at index .. key(x,y) ..

Comment: 300, 000 can grow upto 500,000

Comment: I the way you need   (both the result near each other) using relation approch  tjere aren't much chioices... anyway  .. hope this is useful for you

Comment: I have update the  answer ..  anyway is not fair change the question after a firts answer .. i hope the asnwer is correct and useful and being rate as right .

Comment: Thanks. The answer is correct (I assume , cannot even validate that), but it is not useful to me. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
select variable,count(x),count(y) from 
(select distinct x as variable,x,y from my_table
union all
select distinct y as variable, x,y from my_table)v
group by variable order by variable;
```

Comment: both the counts are same